# ami linux nginx 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, nginx

I'm using AWS m4 large (2vCPU,8Gib memory) AMI Linux os with nginx & php-fpm configuration like this

nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
    worker_processes 2;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

    # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }

    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

       # access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

        #keepalive_timeout   65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

       # server_names_hash_bucket_size 1024;
        server_names_hash_max_size 1024;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript
server_names_hash_bucket_size 100;

#limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;
#limit_req zone=one burst=10;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/servers/*.conf;
}
```

www.conf

```
[www]

user = apache
group = apache

listen= /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm-7.0.sock

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 140
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
pm.max_requests = 500

;pm = ondemand
;pm.max_children = 500
;pm.max_requests = 10000

pm.status_path = /status
ping.path = /ping

;slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log
;request_slowlog_timeout = 5s
request_terminate_timeout = 1m
rlimit_core = unlimited

php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/7.0/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/7.0/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/7.0/wsdlcache
```

sometimes it show error 502 bad gateway and 504 gateway timeout when high traffic load,
how to handle and optimize php-fpm on high traffic so It's keep stable

Thanks.

Comment: You can find bottleneck in your PHP application and make it faster. Or set up more powerfull server or set more resources form php-fpm.

Answer (score 1):

You got 502, that is because your server is too busy to response any requests. Specifically, request client cannot get read results in its max read time limitation.

You got 504, which is from nginx. Specifically, your nginx cannot get read results in its max read time limitation. Its configuration like this:

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;

fastcgi_send_timeout 600;

fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
```

In case of high concurrency, big traffic may bring symptoms like high cpu/men usage and load average. How to handle high concurrency is complicated.

In your case,

1) you can project your resources reasonably. Add some servers if needed, and keep your cluster can process triple traffic.

2) limit request in your nginx.conf:

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=myRateLimit:10m rate=10r/s;
}
server {
    location / {
        limit_req zone=myRateLimit;
        proxy_pass http://your_upstream;
    }
}
```

3) other methods may be optimize your system architecture